# Angular 7 Protractor Non-Angular LoginPage

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

In an Angular Project I started working on E2E Tests. I'm using Protractor + Jasmine to create and run tests.

The WebApp I'm trying to test starts with a login page which is a non Angular Page provided by our customer. After successfully logging in the User gets redirected to our WebApp which then is an Angular Application.
Running an E2E test right now forces me to manually login to the WebApp. (Our plan in the future is to send an access token on starting a test so we bypass the login page.)

What I'm wondering about now is on the current workflow. Does Protractor wait until I'm successfully logged in and starts its tests when recognizing Angular? Or does it expect the whole Application to be Angular and tests fail right away? If so I guess step one would be to implement the access token to bypass the non Angular part and write the actual tests after that. It would be great to get some feedback on my thoughts since there's no experience in our team about E2E tests at all and searching the web didn't satisfy because mostly the results are pretty old and related to AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

If the login is non Angular just turn off the sync while the script is performing the login and once you are logged turn on the angular again:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
//Perform the login
browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
//webApp with angular
```

Comment: That or `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)` to turn off, and then pass in true to turn it back on. [ignoreSynchronization](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/e77885d7a60fd5a56bf624a5307fd41582f10bca/lib/browser.ts#L216) is deprecated.

Comment: @tehbeardedone thanks for the info, already updated my script hehe